# Linq to objects when object is null VS Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have this Linq to object query:

```
var result = Users.Where(u => u.Address.Country.Code == 12)
```

I get an exception if the Address or the Country are null.
Why this query doesn't check if the address is null and just after that procced?
This way I won't need to write this terrible query:

```
var result = Users.Where(u => u.Address != null &&
                              u.Address.Country != null &&  
                              u.Address.Country.Code == 12)
```

In Linq to SQL the first query wiil do the job(from other reasons of course).

Is the a way to avoid the "null checks" in linq to object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, "null" is treated inconsistently in C# (and in many other programming languages). Nullable arithmetic is *lifted*. That is, if you do arithmetic on nullable integers, and none of the operands are null, then you get the normal answer, but if any of them are null, you get null. But the "member access" operator is *not* lifted; if you give a null operand to the member access "." operator, it throws an exception rather than returning a null value.

Were we designing a type system from scratch, we might say that *all* types are nullable, and that *any* expression that contains a null operand produces a null result regardless of the types of the operands. So calling a method with a null receiver *or a null argument* would produce a null result. That system makes a whole lot of sense, but obviously it is far too late for us to implement that now; millions upon millions of lines of code have been written that expects the current behaviour.

We have considered adding a "lifted" member access operator, perhaps notated `.?`. So you could then say `where user.?Address.?Country.?Code == 12` and that would produce a nullable int that could then be compared to 12 as nullable ints normally are. However, this has never gotten past the "yeah, that might be nice in a future version" stage of the design process so I would not expect it any time soon.

---

UPDATE: The "Elvis" operator mentioned above was implemented in C# 6.0.

Comment: And now it is implemented in the language (if the other way around syntactically) but is not implemented in LINQ SQL translation as a no-op so can't be easily used.

Answer (score 5):

No, it is a null reference exception just like accessing `var x = u.Address.Country.Code;` would be a `NullReferenceException`.

You must always make sure what you are de-referencing is not `null` in LINQ to objects, as you would with any other code statements.

You can do this either using the `&&` logic you have, or you could chain `Where` clauses as well (though this would contain more iterators and probably perform slower):

```
var result = Users.Where(u => u.Address != null)
                  .Where(u.Address.Country != null)
                  .Where(u.Address.Country.Code == 12);
```

I've seen some `Maybe()` extension methods written that let you do the sort of thing you want.  Some people do/don't like these because they are extension methods that operate on a `null` reference.  I'm not saying that's good or bad, just that some people feel that violates good OO-like behavior.

For example, you could create an extension method like:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    // returns default if LHS is null
    public static TResult Maybe<TInput, TResult>(this TInput value, Func<TInput, TResult> evaluator)
        where TInput : class
    {
        return (value != null) ? evaluator(value) : default(TResult);
    }

    // returns specified value if LHS is null
    public static TResult Maybe<TInput, TResult>(this TInput value, Func<TInput, TResult> evaluator, TResult failureValue)
        where TInput : class
    {
        return (value != null) ? evaluator(value) : failureValue;
    }
}
```

And then do:

```
var result = Users.Where(u => u.Maybe(x => x.Address)
                  .Maybe(x => x.Country)
                  .Maybe(x => x.Code) == 12);
```

Essentially, this just cascades the `null` down the chain (or default value in the case of a non-reference type).

**UPDATE**:

If you'd like to supply a non-default failure value (say Code is -1 if any part is null), you'd just pass the new failure value into Maybe():

```
// if you wanted to compare to zero, for example, but didn't want null
// to translate to zero, change the default in the final maybe to -1
var result = Users.Where(u => u.Maybe(x => x.Address)
                  .Maybe(x => x.Country)
                  .Maybe(x => x.Code, -1) == 0);
```

Like I said, this is just one of many solutions.  Some people don't like being able to call extension methods from `null` reference types, but it is an option that some people tend to use to get around these `null` cascading issues.

Currently, however, there is not a null-safe de-reference operator built into C#, so you either live with the conditional null checks like you had before, chain your `Where()` statements so that they will filter out the `null`, or build something to let you cascade the `null` like the `Maybe()` methods above.

Comment: Note that if comparing the `Code` to `0` it would return `true` even if any parent property was `null` (since `0` is the default for the type).

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: Yep, that's true.  This is just one overload of many, I actually have several overloads in the library I use to supply other defaults.  For example.... (see updated code).

Comment: I really don't like those maybe's, harder to understand when you read the code, almost as much code.

Comment: @Magnus: As I said, I'm just offering an option, some people do/don't like them.  I'm not saying he should/shouldn't use them, just saying it's something some developers write to help with null handling.